# when i press a tool bar button in any view it should load my root view or main view

Tags: iphone, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

i am new to this iphone....

i hav navigation controller ,itoolbar having the button in all view and when user gets taps this button it should load first view or main view ...
how should i do it

Comment: don't get it. can you post some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: and i have to load view with one section which is selected or  touches by user  in prev view

Comment: previously posted answer was working